# Conditional routing angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I would like to ask, for instance, i have 2 groups of users, privileged and non-privileged. I have a nav bar with a button on it and both groups of users will use the same button.

When a privileged user clicks the button, he will be directs to the privileged screen. When a non-privileged user clicks the button, he will be directs to non-privileged screen.

Any idea how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Guard which redirect the user to a specific path based on some logic:

https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access